# ansible_network_ os not valid attribute error

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and I am trying to run this playbook. I get an error stating "ansible_network_os is not valid attribute to play". Can you please let me know what could be wrong with my script?

```yaml
---
- name: configure interfaces setting
  hosts: switches
  connection: network_cli
  ansible_network_os: cisco.ios.ios
  tasks:
    - name: configure interface
      ios_config:
        before:
          - default interface Gi0/3
        lines:
          - ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
        after:
          -no shutdown
        parents: interface Gi0/3
```

Answer (score 2):

`ansible_network_os` is a variable. It's not a playbook keyword. See for example [Prerequisites](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/network_best_practices_2.5.html#prerequisites). To fix the play put the variable among variables. For example,

```yaml
---
- name: configure interfaces setting
  hosts: switches
  connection: network_cli
  vars:
    ansible_network_os: cisco.ios.ios
  tasks:
    - name: configure interface
      ...
```

Notes:

- See [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#playbook-keywords) what keywords can be used at various blocks.
- The variable `ansible_connection` can be used also as the play keyword `connection`. This can be confusing because not all `ansible_*` variables have keyword equivalent.
- To avoid this kind of confusion put such variables into the inventory. This is a better place compared to a playbook because the connection type doesn't change in most cases during a play. If it does you can override it anytime on a higher precedence level inside a play. See [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence).

Comment: i have done the change now iam getting an error.PLAY [configure interfaces setting] ********************************************

TASK [configure interface] *****************************************************
fatal: [sw1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No authentication methods available"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
sw1                        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Answer (score 0):

Much appreciated your help, the other issue is resolved by providing the username and password parameter into the play.